# Random question downvotes

Tags: support, serial-voting

I logged into my profile today to find myself missing some rep. Not too much, just enough to make me question it. Turns out all of my (three!) questions have been downvoted.

1. [How to test InputMethodService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278241/how-to-test-inputmethodservice)
2. [Get reference to layout from DialogPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074340/get-reference-to-layout-from-dialogpreference)
3. [Performance concerns when storing multiple bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882987/performance-concerns-when-storing-multiple-bitmaps)

All three were downvoted within 1 minute of each other.

As far as I'm concerned there is absolutely nothing wrong with these questions. So my questions are:

1. Should a user be allowed to downvote all of my answers in such quick succession? Given that there is presumably a motive?
2. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Bottom line: nothing you can do at the moment, good chance you'll get the points back.

Comment: Cool thanks, I did search but I didn't know there was a name for it ;)

Comment: Yup, there's a name to almost anything here on Meta. :)

Comment: Same thing's happened to me, but over several days. Using conjecture, I can be reasonably sure it's the same person, trying to avoid the downvotes being rolled back. I don't often get downvotes, so in the vicinity of ten in three days makes me suspicious. But, nothing to do, since the script hasn't caught it. =)

Comment: I've had this before when I've apparently annoyed someone, e.g. by flagging their question as a duplicate - shortly afterwards several of my questions and/or answers will suddenly have been down-voted for no apparent reason. I guess you just learn to live with it.